# VB.NET error "Value of type 'Ushort' cannot be converted to 'Ushort()'" reading two-dimensional array of bytes from a native C++ DLL

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net, dll

I'm getting VB error:  "Value of type 'Ushort' cannot be converted to 'Ushort()'".

I have a VB.NET windows app that calls a function in a native (C++) DLL, to read a specific 256 byte page from an array of the pages within the DLL.

VISUAL-C++ declaration within the DLL source, of the function....

```
extern "C" BASICDLL_API int __stdcall My_Read_High_Speed_Data(unsigned char ptr, unsigned short *buf)
{
    return BDLL_ReadBlock(0x00300000 + ptr, (unsigned char *)buf);
}
```

VB.NET Declaration of the function in the DLL................

```vb
<DllImport("MyDll.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Public Function My_Read_Parameters(ByVal board As Byte, ByVal params As UShort()) As Int32
End Function
```

Declaration of the VB.NET buffer to hold the 64 pages of 256 bytes each, from DLL...............

```vb
Dim input_page_buffer( 64, 256 ) As UInt16
```

VB.NET function to read the page from the DLL...................

```
function poll()                         
    dim page_index = 1
    dim success = My_Read_High_Speed_Data( page_index, input_page_buffer(1, 1)  )
end function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dll import function

```vb
..., ByVal params As UShort()
```

calls for a `UShort()` as the second argument, while the c++ has

```vb
..., unsigned short *buf)
```

Change the dll import to `UShort`

Comment: Considering these facts: **1)** The parameter is called `buf` (which probably is short for _buffer_) **2)** The parameter is casted into an `unsigned char*` (which is usually mapped to a byte array) **3)** The function internally calls another function called _BDLL\_Read **Block**_ -- ...I think that the parameter should at the very least be an array of some sort. If had to guess `BDLL_ReadBlock()` fills the `buf` "array" with the bytes read from (whatever).

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question properly ( *:)* ) I think I understand what you're trying to do... The C++ function is expecting a byte array for its `buf` parameter, which is then filled with 256 bytes by the `BDLL_ReadBlock()` function.

Why you have declared the parameter as `unsigned short*` rather than `unsigned byte*` I don't understand, since `BDLL_ReadBlock()` clearly expects the latter.

Anyway, to fix the issue you would have to switch from a *two-dimensional array* to a [***jagged array***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/#BKMK_JaggedArrays). This is because they do different things:

- In a two-dimensional array you have all items laid out in a grid, pretty much like a fixed coordinate system:

```vb
    Array(3, 3):
        0  1  2  3
     0  A  B  C  D
     1  E  F  G  H
     2  I  J  K  L
     3  M  N  O  P
```

- However, a *jagged array* is an ***array of arrays***, which means you have a set of columns and rows where the columns doesn't necessarily have to be of the same amount for every row:

  ```vb
  Array(3)(3):
       0   1   2   3
   0  {A,  B,  C,  D}
   1  {E,  F,  G,  H}
   2  {I,  J,  K,  L}
   3  {M,  N,  O,  P}

  Array(3)(x):
       0   1   2   3   4
   0  {A,  B}
   1  {C,  D,  E,  F,  G}
   2  {H,  I,  J}
   3  {K}
  ```

The difference when accessing items is that in a 2D array you can only get ***ONE item*** at a time:

```vb
Array(1, 3) = H
```

...whereas in a jagged array you don't necessarily have to access *only one* item, but you can also reference an entire row:

```vb
'Single item.
Array(1)(3) = H

'Entire row.
Array(1) = {E, F, G, H}
```

---

Moving on...

Since `BDLL_ReadBlock()` seems to expect an array of bytes you should change your C++ method to take one as well (if you have access to the source, that is):

```cpp
extern "C" BASICDLL_API int __stdcall My_Read_High_Speed_Data(unsigned char ptr, unsigned char *buf)
{
    return BDLL_ReadBlock(0x00300000 + ptr, buf);
}
```

Then change the VB.NET declaration:

```vb
<DllImport("MyDll.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function My_Read_High_Speed_Data(ByVal ptr As Byte, ByVal buf As Byte()) As Integer
End Function
```

Finally, change your VB.NET array to a jagged one, instead of a 2D array:

```vb
Dim input_page_buffer(64 - 1)() As Byte
'In VB.NET you specify the upper bound INDEX of an array, not how many items it should contain.
'Thus "Dim Array(64)" creates an array of 65 items (since indexes are zero-based), and "Dim Array(64 - 1)" or "Dim Array(63)" creates an array of 64 items.
```

The only backside to this is that you must initialize the inner arrays of a jagged array separately:

```vb
For x = 0 To input_page_buffer.Length - 1
    input_page_buffer(x) = New Byte(256 - 1) {}
Next
```

**And finally**, calling the function:

```vb
Function poll()
    Dim page_index As Byte = 1

    'input_page_buffer(0) gives you the first 256-byte array.
    Dim success As Integer = My_Read_High_Speed_Data(page_index, input_page_buffer(0))

    ...
End Function
```

---

If you **cannot** change the source of the C++ code then just replace every `Byte(...)` in my code with `UShort(...)` and you should be good to go!